# Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu 19.04 GeForce MX150 don't work (MateBook X Pro, dual boot)

Tags: 19.04, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-prime

I installed Nvidia drivers 4.30.

What I see after typing:

```
nvidia-smi
```

is:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver...
```

Comment: What is 4.30 driver? How did you install it?

Comment: 430.14
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430